# how to copy file to new directory using openfiledialog in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

I need to copy an mp3 file chosen with OpenFileDialog to a new directory. The problem is all the files inside the folder copies to the new directory. I want to copy only the specific file chosen in that folder. pls help.

note: after opening the mp3 file, Textbox1 will display the source path of the file(sourcepath). then Textbox2 will display the new path(destPath)  after hitting the save button.

```
 Private Shared Sub CopyDirectory(ByVal sourcePath As String, ByVal destPath As String)
    If Not Directory.Exists(destPath) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destPath)
    End If

    For Each file__1 As String In Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(sourcePath))
        Dim dest As String = Path.Combine(destPath, Path.GetFileName(file__1))
        File.Copy(file__1, dest)
    Next

    For Each folder As String In Directory.GetDirectories(Path.GetDirectoryName(sourcePath))
        Dim dest As String = Path.Combine(destPath, Path.GetFileName(folder))
        CopyDirectory(folder, dest)
    Next
End Sub

 Private Sub ButtonSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonSave.Click
    Dim sourcepath As String = ""
    Dim DestPath As String = "C:\Users\Big Boss Eis\Desktop\vb file maintenance\fileMaintenance with database\fileMaintenance"
    sourcepath = TextBox1.Text
    CopyDirectory(sourcepath, DestPath)
End Sub

 Private Sub OpenFile_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OpenFile.Click
    If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK) Then
   AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL() = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
   End If
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your entire CopyDirectory function with this

```
Private Shared Sub CopyDirectory(ByVal sourcePath As String, ByVal destPath As String)
    If System.IO.File.Exists( sourcePath ) = True Then

        System.IO.File.Copy( sourcePath , destPath )
        MsgBox("File Copied")

    End If
End Sub
```

Edited through mobile phone, excuse any errors

Comment: what's the value of FileToCopy?

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please.